# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" while connecting to postgress from Spring Boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

[This is the command prompt where I have created container and database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w8yr.png)
application.yml

```
app:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgresDB
    username: postgres
    password: password
    pool-size: 30
```

I am new to docker. I have created one container in docker and in that container I have created Postgres DB but while connecting to the database I am getting the following error:

Stacktrace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:525) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:146) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56) [flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:80) [flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:456) [flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:159) [flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) [spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) [spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) [spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.freecodecamp.freecodecamp.FreecodecampApplication.main(FreecodecampApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

2020-05-31 15:40:31.124  WARN 18004 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: How are you launching the application and database containers?  Please edit the question to include these details in the question as text, not behind a link and not as a screen shot of a terminal window.  `localhost` in Docker usually means "this container" (not "this host") so that's not generally the right location for an application to specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run into issues like this when you have Postgres already running as a service on your machine with the same port as the docker's.

Try to stop the postgres service running locally. On Windows, open Task Manager switch to 'services' tab and search for `postgresql-x64-15` or `postgresql-x64-xx` where `xx` is your postgres version. Open context menu on it (right-click) and select `stop`. On other platforms you can as well just google how to locate and stop services.

If you still wish to maintain both, edit your docker compose to use a different port map then recreate the container i.e

from

```
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
```

to

```
ports:
  - "5433:5432"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the tracktrace,

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

your application cannot login to your DB because your credentials are not right. Are you sure about username: postgres and password: password?

Can you try using a DBMS to connect to your DB using those credentials?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w8yr.png here I have given same credentials which I'm using for the postgress connection

Comment: You are giving "password" to the docker but actually on your DB, user "postgres" is not using that password. Try to set "password" as a password for user "postgres" directly via psql: `ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update passwords in localhost.properties and application.yml files once you change the password using the command: ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'postgres@123'(previous password)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).